# Map array inside object

Tags: javascript

I' trying to get the response of my API and map the peson whit his topic.
I map the person whitout problem, but I can t do the same for the topic..
I already did:

```
const people = props.data.people // get people array
const name = people.map(el => el.person.name) // get the name
const a =  people.map(el => el.topic)
```

in `a` I get the topic, but here returns the two arrays for separated and I need map the person whit the topic, and even then I can 't acces to value and item.. what should I do?

Thanks (sorry for my english)

this is the response:

```
{
  "people": [
    {
      "person": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Arlo Johnston"
      },
      "topic": [
        {
          "item": "dogs",
          "value": 1
        },
        {
          "item": "cats",
          "value": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "person": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Prof. Conner Macejkovic"
      },
      "topic": [
        {
          "item": "dogs",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "item": "cats",
          "value": 5
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please add the expected output.

Comment: are you sure that `props.data.people` works? since `people` appears to be a `params` property in response example you showed

Comment: Yes, sorry I edited now. I recive params for props. The expected output is gona be something like: Arlo Johnston topic: dogs : 1 , cats: 0 , Prof. Conner Macejkovic topic: dogs: 5, cats: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const nameWithTopics = people.map(el => ({ name: el.person.name, topics: el.topics }))
```

Comment: this shows **{name: "Arlo Johnston", topic: undefined}**

Comment: Is it `topic` or `topics` in the response?

Comment: topics! sorry, my bad! now it works great! thank you very much!